# Generate histogram based on count of rows with associations having counts greater than one per day over a time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry for the confusing title, but I don't quite know how to phrase the query I'm trying to generate and I'm stumped as to how to do it. Say I have a table `websites` that has columns `id`, `domain`, and `created_at`. I have another table, `visitors`, that has columns `id`, `website_id`, `created_at`.

What I'm trying to determine is out of the websites that were created *over a month ago* and that have had *at least one visitor in the past month*, how can I group the websites by the number of days in the last month they had one or more visitors?

I'm essentially trying to generate a histogram with the x-axis # of days with at least one visitor in the past month (so it will go 1-30), and the y-axis # of websites in the table that have had that number of days with at least one visitor.

Here's some example data with what I'm looking to glean:

**Websites**

```
╔════╤═══════════════════╤════════════╗
║ id │ domain            │ created_at ║
╠════╪═══════════════════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ example.com       │ 9-28-2018  ║
╟────┼───────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ google.com        │ 1-1-2018   ║
╟────┼───────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ test.com          │ 2-1-2018   ║
╟────┼───────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 4  │ amazon.com        │ 3-1-2018   ║
╟────┼───────────────────┼────────────╢
║ 5  │ stackoverflow.com │ 1-2-2013   ║
╚════╧═══════════════════╧════════════╝
```

**Visitors**

```
╔════╤════════════╤════════════════════════════╗
║ id │ website_id │ created_at                 ║
╠════╪════════════╪════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ 1          │ 2018-09-15 01:34:07.917448 ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ 2          │ 2018-09-28T17:51:35+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 3  │ 2          │ 2018-09-28T17:50:35+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 4  │ 2          │ 2018-09-28T17:51:21+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 5  │ 2          │ 2017-11-15 01:34:07.917448 ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 6  │ 3          │ 2018-09-14T17:50:08+50:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 7  │ 4          │ 2018-09-15T16:50:01+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 8  │ 4          │ 2018-09-15T16:50:09+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 9  │ 4          │ 2018-09-16T16:50:10+32:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 10 │ 4          │ 2018-09-04T09:50:09+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 11 │ 5          │ 2017-11-15 01:34:07.917448 ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 12 │ 5          │ 2018-09-06T09:50:09+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 13 │ 5          │ 2018-09-07T09:50:07+12:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 14 │ 5          │ 2018-09-08T09:50:02+40:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 15 │ 5          │ 2018-09-09T09:50:19+23:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 16 │ 5          │ 2018-09-10T09:50:12+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 17 │ 5          │ 2018-09-10T09:50:06+00:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 18 │ 6          │ 2018-09-02T09:50:01+18:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 19 │ 6          │ 2018-09-03T09:50:02+47:00  ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 20 │ 6          │ 2018-09-04T09:50:07+13:00  ║
╚════╧════════════╧════════════════════════════╝
```

**Output**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════╗
║ Number of Active Days in Last Month │ Number of Websites ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════╣
║ 0                                   │ 0                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 1                                   │ 2                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 2                                   │ 0                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 3                                   │ 2                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 4                                   │ 0                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 5                                   │ 1                  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────╢
║ 6                                   │ 0                  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════╧════════════════════╝
```

**Explanation**

- None of the websites had no visitors in the last month.
- Websites 2 and 3 each had one active day over the last month. Website 1 did as well, but it's excluded because it was also created within the last month.
- No websites had two active days in the last month.
- Websites 4 and 6 each had 3 active days in the last month.
- Website 5 had 5 active days.
- No websites had 6+ active days in the last month.

Comment: Okay example data included!

Comment: This reads like a "do my work for me'"-question. Please include what you have tried, and why it doesn't work or what you're stuck on.

Comment: Not really, this isn't my actual data model at all - it's a far simplified version that I adapted to be more understandable for a forum like SO. I'm not super experienced with SQL and this is over my head. This is also a fairly generalized use-case of generating a distribution for a metric like DAU - I'm just not super experienced with SQL, and that's the whole point of SO.